# Unable to find xpath "/html" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I was implementing capybara for a app flow. I have `features/step_definitions/anonymous_booking_steps.rb` with two steps

- for just visiting the root path
- expecting an element in next step for the above page

I am getting this error:-

`Unable to find xpath "/html" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

Comment: ...so...?what's the problem? :)

Comment: Show your test and steps code

Comment: If you want to see a working example you can look [here](https://github.com/mikejramsey56/ruby_cucumber_webdriver/tree/master/features).  See features/helloWorld.feature.  In the step defintions ignore the calls to wait_for_jquery(timeout: 20)
  wait_for_page_load_to_complete(timeout: 20), I was just testing the methods out. You don't need them.

Comment: Tom is right. If you want to ask your questions better, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Old hands **hate** poorly asked questions and will punish you for them with a down vote..